# Better Alloy model of n-queens?

Tags: alloy

Below is an Alloy model of the n-queens problem (well, actually, of the 4-queens problem). I'm wondering if there is a better solution? Notice in my solution I use `next` and `prev` repeatedly to eliminate queens on a diagonal; that seems pretty klunky.

```
open util/ordering[Row]

sig Row {}

one sig Column0 {
    row: Row
}

one sig Column1 {
    row: Row
}

one sig Column2 {
    row: Row
}

one sig Column3 {
    row: Row
}

fact {
   #Row = 4
}

fact {
    Column0.row != Column1.row
    Column0.row != Column2.row
    Column0.row != Column3.row
    Column1.row != next.(Column0.row)
    Column2.row != next.next.(Column0.row)
    Column3.row != next.next.next.(Column0.row)
    Column1.row != prev.(Column0.row)
    Column2.row != prev.prev.(Column0.row)
    Column3.row != prev.prev.(Column0.row)

    Column1.row != Column2.row
    Column1.row != Column3.row
    Column2.row != next.(Column1.row)
    Column3.row != next.next.(Column1.row)
    Column2.row != prev.(Column1.row)
    Column3.row != prev.prev.(Column1.row)

    Column2.row != Column3.row
    Column3.row != next.(Column2.row)
    Column3.row != prev.(Column2.row)
}

pred Show {}

run Show for 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on what you mean by better.
Your solution has some advantages: optimized for 4 queens/4x4 boards, minimal number of concepts, nice default graphical visualization of instance generated, but comes with its drawback. (doesn't work for a different number of queens/rows/columns, and "klunky constraints")

I present to you an alternative solution I came up with which has its shortcomings (more concepts + quantification in constraints might slow down analysis) but also its advantages : concise and imho more readable constraints and flexibility (will work for any number of cols/rows/queens)

```
one sig Board{
    cols: seq Column,
    rows: seq Row,
    q: set Queen
}
sig Row {
  id:Int
}{
   id=Board.rows.idxOf[this]
   this in Board.rows.elems
}

sig Column {
  id:Int
}{
  id=Board.cols.idxOf[this]
  this in Board.cols.elems
}
sig Queen{
    x:Column,
    y:Row
}
pred aligned[q1,q2:Queen]{
   q1.y=q2.y 
   or 
   q1.x=q2.x  
   or some a,b:Int{
       add[q1.x.id,a]= q2.x.id 
       add[q1.y.id,b]= q2.y.id
       a=b or a=sub[0,b]
    } 
}
pred Show {
   no disj q1,q2:Queen| aligned[q1,q2]
}
run Show for exactly 4 Row, exactly 4 Column, exactly 4 Queen
```

Note that the instances obtained by analysis will be hard to visualize without an appropriate theme. Here is one you can import that will produce a nice visualization: https://pastebin.com/wwKP6g9h

Note2: you need to forbid integer overflow or set the bandwidth of integer to be large enough for the additions in the aligned predicate to behave as expected

Note3: the id field was added to enable showing the id of the row/column as attribute (not supported for sequences) in the theme.

**edit** the scope of seq will have to be manually assigned for this model to work with n > 4.

Following is an alternative implementation without sequence (for those who do not want to bother with assigning an extra scope)

```
one sig Board{
    cols: set Column,
    rows: set Row,
    q: set Queen
}
sig Row {
  id: disj Int
}{
   this in Board.rows
}

fact id{
    all r:Row| (sub[r.id,1] in Row.id or r.id=1) and r.id>0
    all c:Column| (sub[c.id,1] in Column.id or c.id=1) and c.id>0
}

sig Column {
  id: disj Int
}{
  this in Board.cols
}
sig Queen{
    x:Column,
    y:Row
}
pred aligned[q1,q2:Queen]{
   q1.y=q2.y 
   or 
   q1.x=q2.x  
   or some a,b:Int{
       add[q1.x.id,a]= q2.x.id 
       add[q1.y.id,b]= q2.y.id
       a=b or a=sub[0,b]
    } 
}
pred Show {
   no disj q1,q2:Queen| aligned[q1,q2]
}
run Show for exactly 4 Row, exactly 4 Column, exactly 4 Queen
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Thank you Loïc Gammaitoni

Comment: My pleasure ;-)

Comment: Hi Loïc, I tried running your solution for a 5 x 5 chessboard but Alloy found no instances. I tried various values for Int, including 4 Int, 5 Int, and 6 Int but still no instance. In the Options menu I have set Prevent Overflows: yes. Any thoughts on why Alloy is not finding any instances?

Comment: You need to set a scope of 5 to seq as well. ,5 seq (see here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843452/how-to-define-scope-of-int/26844037#26844037 )

Comment: edited answer. I provided another implementation who doesn't use sequences. it reduces the complexity of the generated CNF and thus improves analysis time

Comment: Thank you again Loïc! Adding , 5 seq makes it work for a 5 x 5 chessboard!